# How to handle alert for Safari browser in selenium webdriver?

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Code is running fine in all browser but alert cant handle when I run case in safari browser. Alert is not showing in safari following expection I got.

> "org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: A modal dialog was
>   opened. The SafariDriver does not support interacting with modal
>   dialogs. To avoid hanging your test, the alert has been dismissed. For
>   more information, see
>   http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3862: Please
>   provide a valid email address."

I put time wait also but no use.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below approach to Handle alert for safari before perform any action :-

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
js.executeScript("window.alert = function(){ return true;}");
```

This java script override the alert box functionality on webpage where you automate you test case.

You need to execute it before those action where you are getting `UnhandledAlertException`

For eg :- suppose you have a `WebElement el` and when you clicked on `el`, you are getting `UnhandledAlertException` then you need to execute as :-

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
js.executeScript("window.alert = function(){ return true;}");
el.click();
```

Answer (score -1):

I handle the JavaScript alert for Safari browser in the Selenium WebDriver, which I am sharing here.

```
public static boolean isAlertPresent(WebDriver driver) {
        try {
            //driver.switchTo().alert();
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
            return true;
        } // try
        catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        } // catch
    }

if(isAlertPresent(driver)) {
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.println("Alert Text : "+alert.getText());
    alert.accept();
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
}
```

Note: Make sure that these lines of code are added soon after clicking the tab/button which produces a modal dialog box (popup).